# Problem statement related to Coset Intersection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

**Notation** : $\times $ used for Cartesian product, Sym means symmetric group, $\tau, \Delta \subseteq \Sigma$ and $\le$ for subgroup.

**Input** : $L\le Sym(\tau) \times Sym(\Delta)$; $z \in Sym(\tau \times \Delta);$ $\pi \subseteq \tau \times \Delta$.

**Output :** $(Lz)_{\pi} = \{x \in Lz \mid \pi ^x = \pi\}.$

Output is either $\phi$ or a right coset( of the group $L_{\pi}$).

> I am not able to understand $(Lz)_{\pi}$ completely. $L$ makes sense to me it is a subgroup as given above. $\pi$ is also not a problem but $Lz$ I am not able to understand. As given in the problem statement $z \in Sym(\tau \times \Delta)$, but it should be that  $z \in Sym(\tau )\times Sym( \Delta)$.

**My questions** : 1) Is $Sym(\tau )\times Sym( \Delta) \le Sym(\tau \times \Delta)$ up to isomorphism ?

2) How $(Lz)_{\pi}$ is a coset ?

Comment: Nice with notation outline. If every one could only be so clear. Unfortunately I am still confused on the $\tau, \Delta \subseteq \sum$ and $\le $ subgroup line? Are they just two subsets of $\sum$?

Comment: Also the output part are you to prove something about it?

Comment: Why is it labeled output? From my perspective it seems just a definition of another set perhaps to be used in the study of the statement under " My question"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to Question 1 is yes. The action is given by $(a,b)^{(g,h)} = (a^g,b^h)$ for $(a,b) \in \tau \times \Sigma$ and $(g,h) \in {\rm Sym}(\tau) \times {\rm Sym}(\Sigma)$. Or, in other words, the element $(g,h) \in {\rm Sym}(\tau) \times {\rm Sym}(\Sigma)$ is mapped to the element $\phi(g,h) \in {\rm Sym}(\tau \times \Sigma)$ that maps $(a,b) \in \tau \times \Sigma$ to $(a^g,b^h)$.

For Question 2, suppose that $(Lz)_\pi$ is nonempty and hence $lz \in (Lz)_\pi$ for some $l \in L$. Then, for $l' \in L$, we have $$l'z  \in (Lz)_\pi \Leftrightarrow \pi^{lz} = \pi^{l'z} \Leftrightarrow l'l^{-1} \in L_\pi,$$
so $(Lz)_\pi$ is the right coset $L_\pi lz$ of $L_\pi$.

Comment: To prove $H \le G$ we need to show that for all $a, b$ in $H$ subgroup we need to $ab^{-1}$ belong to $H$. I did not get how you prove the subgroup condition

Comment: Strictly speaking it is isomorphic to a subgroup rather being equal to one. I have defined an injective homomorphism from ${\rm Sym}(\tau) \times {\rm Sym}(\Sigma)$ to ${\rm Sym}(\tau \times \Sigma)$. (It is  clearly a homomorphism and injective.) We use that to identify ${\rm Sym}(\tau) \times {\rm Sym}(\Sigma)$ with its image in ${\rm Sym}(\tau \times \Sigma)$.

Comment: In the answer of second question for some $l \in L$ or $l \in L_{\pi}$

Comment: For some $l \in L$ (as it says).

Comment: I have already defined the map in  my answer to the first question, but I have taken $(g,h) \in {\rm Sym}(\tau) \times {\rm Sym}(\Sigma)$.